# looking to get a query constructed out for oracle sql developer output

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Existing table

[image: Existing table]

Output query should render this

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and take the `MAX` of each column:

```sql
SELECT event,
       MAX(numericval) AS quantity,
       MAX(details) AS status
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY event
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (event, elements, numericval, details) AS
SELECT 1, 'quality', 5, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'status', NULL, 'yes' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'quality', 10, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'status', NULL, 'no' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'quality', 15, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'status', NULL, 'yes' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | EVENT | QUANTITY | STATUS |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 5 | yes |
> | 2 | 10 | no |
> | 3 | 15 | yes |

---

For your update, you can use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT event,
       MAX(CASE elements WHEN 'quality' THEN numericval END) AS quantity,
       MAX(CASE elements WHEN 'status' THEN details END) AS status,
       MAX(CASE elements WHEN 'Lot' THEN numericval END) AS lot
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY event
```

Which for the updated data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (event, elements, numericval, details) AS
SELECT 1, 'quality', 5, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'status', NULL, 'yes' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 1 , 'Lot',1,null from dual union all
SELECT 2, 'quality', 10, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'status', NULL, 'no' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 2 , 'Lot',3,null from dual union all
SELECT 3, 'quality', 15, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'status', NULL, 'yes' FROM DUAL union all
select 3, 'Lot', 4,null from dual;
```

Outputs:

> | EVENT | QUANTITY | STATUS | LOT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 5 | yes | 1 |
> | 2 | 10 | no | 3 |
> | 3 | 15 | yes | 4 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d465b45de44779a6a7f6264a53b010c0)*

Comment: this will only work if there is only one numeric value but my situation is as below CREATE TABLE table_name (event, elements, numericval, details) AS
SELECT 1, 'quality', 5, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'status', NULL, 'yes' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 1 , 'Lot',1,null from dual union all
SELECT 2, 'quality', 10, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'status', NULL, 'no' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
select 2 , 'Lot',3,null from dual union all
SELECT 3, 'quality', 15, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'status', NULL, 'yes' FROM DUAL union all
select 3,'Lot',4,null from dual ;